# Unable to connect to internet with VirtualBox using bridged adapter?

Tags: networking, virtualbox

I am trying to connect to the internet using bridged Adapter mode in virtual-box ? the host machine (win 7) connected to the internet,but the guest machine(vm machine) can not connect!

thanks in advance.

Comment: Questions like this are better off on http://serverfault.com/ or super user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To connect to internet using bridged adapter, you should configure the virtual machine network adapter to use the configuration like the host machine (don't forget not to duplicate the IP address).
Or if you want simpler way you can use NAT bridged adapter.

Comment: i put static IP in the CentOS machine ,and i am open it from host(win7) and it is work.

Answer (score 2):

You may try ping an internet IP address, if it's connected by domain name doesn't work, go to edit resolv.conf to add name server manually
resolv.conf
nameserver 192.168.1.1

If you set up DHCP at first time to start the interface, this file will be written by DHCP service to the above information.